# add and retrieve elements from an array in Servlet Context

Tags: arrays, servlets

I have an array in the Servlet Context and I would like to add and retrieve elements of this array from different servlets.

How can I do this ?

I do this for getting the entire list:

```
    out.println(getServletContext().getAttribute("list"));
```

list is the name of the array, so what can I do for adding an element to that list, and for getting the element with index 0 ?

Comment: Just like with any other array. What's the problem? What have you tried? Make sure to understand that you'll modify an array from multiple threads, which requires synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted prints the array to the `out` writer. To get a variable referencing the array, just do

```
String[] array = (String[]) getServletContext().getAttribute("list");
```

(assuming the array is an array of Strings, of course).

Comment: in my case is an ArrayList. How would you print the element with index 0 ?

Comment: If it's an `ArrayList<Foo>`, then replace `String[]` by `ArrayList<Foo>` in the code above. And read [the ArrayList javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). This is extremely basic stuff that you should master before doing web programming. BTW, why are you telling that it's an array in your question if it's an ArrayList? An ArrayList and an array are two different things.